# Version Code Error while Uploading Flutter Apk to Play Store

Tags: flutter, apk

Play console is giving error "Use different Version Code".

I have tried everything. Changing the version code in the pubspec.yaml to 2.0.1+2. And then running pub get
Changing the version code in the local.properties file.
Flutter Clean and then build the release. Even then Play Console is giving error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I Was also facing the same problem, and later got to know that my `version code` was defined statically in my `build.gradle` file.*

*Go To Android -> App -> build.gradle file*

And To Change it from there Please check your `build.gradle` file, is the `version Code` coming from `flutterVersionCode` or is it defined `statically`?

```
defaultConfig {
   //...
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger() //See this line, is it same as mine or you have any static version Code set there which is causing the issue.
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: Yeah Well just before reading your answer I saw this defaultConfig block and it version code was defined statically to 1 so I changed it to 2. LOL I also did it statically but now I know the right way. Thanks alot